# Angular form does'nt work the same in different component

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, components

I have a component named **name-editor** containing a form. Like this :

**name-editor.component.html**

```
<p>name editor : </p>
<label>
  Name:
  <input type="text" [formControl]="test">
</label>

<p> Value: {{ test.value }} </p>
```

**name-editor.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-name-editor',
      templateUrl: './name-editor.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./name-editor.component.css']
    })

    export class NameEditorComponent implements OnInit {
      test = new FormControl('test');

      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    }
```

This component works fine when I call it in **app.component.html**. BUT not when I call it in the component **main-view** (and main-view is it-self called in  **app.component.html**). In fact, data from ts code seems not linked to HTML. The error looks like this :

[image]

instead of

[image]

**main-view.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2"><app-menu></app-menu></div>

  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        Specification
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <app-see-specification-parameter></app-see-specification-parameter>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        Data Frame
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <app-name-editor></app-name-editor>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to add the code of **name-editor** directly in the main-view component and it is working too.

I do not understand why the doesn't work in a component at this place.

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz demo?

Comment: are there any errors in console saying <app-name-editor> is not a known element ? Maybe <app-name-editor> is declared in a separate module and is not being exported so the other module can't use it ?